# How to use variables with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I tried reading online tutorials about RegEx, but none of them give me a clear picture of how to find and replace with variables. As I now understand from the comments, regex is for searching only, so to specify, I want to do this using the Atom text editor. Alternatively using php.

What I want to do is to find and replace in this way:

```
"resolution": "800x600"  ---> "width":"800", "height":"600"

"resolution": "1024x768"  ---> "width":"1024", "height":"768"
```

Can anyone please explain how to do this, and how to use variables when replacing with regex?

Comment: Regular expressions are a formalism for matching patterns in strings.  It does not have the construct of a variable, though the containing language will often have a way to provide the functionality you are looking for. But you are not saying which language or showing us the code where you want this to work.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, however, it's not in a language. Preferably I'd want to do it in the Atom text editor. I guess I also can make the changes in php or JavaScript if that is the only way. I will update my question.

Comment: If Atom supports substitution with back references, `"resolution": "(\d+)x(\d+)"` could be substituted with `"width": "\1", "height": "\2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP solution is

```
$re = "/.*?(\\d+)x(\\d+)/m"; 
$str = "\"resolution\": \"800x600\""; 
$subst = "\"width\" : \"$1\", \"height\" : \"$2"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

[**IDEONE DEMO**](http://ideone.com/s4j5fm)

As far as `atom editor` is concerned it supports back references as `$1` etc. as mentioned [here](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/351) and [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/need-help-with-regex-find-and-replace/15003)